# Keyboard shows up in "DialogPreference" type layout with TextEdit

Tags: android, dialog-preference

I have a problem with the keyboard. I've research all the "Stackoverflow", I've tested million of different methods. And still cannot to make the keyboard hidden, when the "Dialog" shows up. May be anybody has a 10000% working solution?

```
public class ConfirmDialog extends DialogPreference implements OnClickListener{

public ConfirmDialog(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

    setPositiveButtonText(R.string.b_ok);
    setNegativeButtonText(R.string.b_cancel);
}

protected View onCreateDialogView(){

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View createdv = inflater.inflate(R.layout.confirm_dialog, null);

          //Here I've tried to hide a keyboard!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    ((EditText) createdv.findViewById(R.id.confirm_name)).setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
            if(hasFocus)
            {
                   getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
            }
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    });

    getDialog().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved…
In XML document right in front of EditText tag I've added…

```
<LinearLayout android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true" 
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="0px" />
```

I've read it [here](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/remove-autofocus-edittext-android).

Comment: well that makes it easy.

Comment: @user922907, Thank you. Extremely clever and very simple. None of he 'regular' solutions here on SO (all variations of your original code sample above) seem to work for a DialogPreference layout.

Answer (score 1):

this how i implement it in my project this method take the view like edittext and hide the soft keyboard

```
private void hidesoftKeyboard(View v) {

    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(v.getWindowToken(), 0);

}
```

feed me back

Comment: I've tried… doesn't work… InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

Comment: could you post your layout and full implementation may i can help you

Comment: I cannot to add the code here. Too long and too many errors. Stackoverflow not allowing.